# Chromecast stopped working - black screen followed by "Cast connection stopped" screen

Tags: streaming, chromecast

I have a problem with Chromecast. Bought two weeks ago, it has been working perfectly for steaming from both my MacBook Air (using Google Chrome) and my iPhone (using supported apps like Youtube & Neflix). Today while streaming a Chrome tab (a video from Amazon Prime), the stream got stuck. I stopped the casting and started it again, but all I received is a black screen for 10 seconds, followed by the blue “lost connection” screen.

I tried restarting my laptop, as well as the chrome://flags#media-router thingy I read about in some other posts, nothing helps. I also tried restoring to factory settings, but it did not solve the problem. When streaming from another laptop (Windows 7), the stream worked for 10 minutes, before the problem started with that laptop as well (TV shows black screen followed by the blue one).

I know the problem is specific to when I stream from Chrome on a laptop, given that I can still stream from supported apps on my iPhone like Youtube.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by calling the Chromecast customer service. For future reference, whoever needs it:

Disconnect Chromecast from power
Disconnect Router from power
After 10 seconds connect router to power
After 1 minute connect Chromecast to power
Once the Chromecast photos start running, wait 10 seconds and then cast your tab.

If this didn't help, they suggested going to your router settings and change to channel 9 or 11.